# How to prevent tomcat automatic shutdown?

Tags: java, tomcat

I am using tomcat 7.0.8 in windows server 2008 remote machine(using it a server machine). Where I have hosted my java webapp running on port 80.

I start the tomcat server by running the startup.batch file. The issue is that the tomcat server shutdowns automatically whenever logoff from remote machine and not using the application for sometime like 30-40mins. I even disabled the tomcat shutdown 8005 but still the problem persists.

Please help me to solve this.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you follow the [Windows service HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/windows-service-howto.html) documentation to run Tomcat as a service ?

Comment: Increase the Tomcat timeout by double clicking on Tomcat server from Server view. You will see Timeout option , there in you can increase its timeout .

Comment: @Adya This works only in Eclipse.

Comment: @Eugene Adell.sure i will try running tomcat as a service.but i see some posts even as a service tomcat shutdowns automatically after a while.

Comment: Version 7.0.8 is very old, it's maybe time for an upgrade.